# How to change data format in custom meta box field

Tags: plugins, custom-field, metabox

I want to chage date format to `d-m-y` means day-month-year format . I have added

```
'date_format' => __( 'd-m-Y', 'cmb2' )
```

But not working. now it's month-day-year formated . Actually i want to change date format like month-day-year to day-month-year.

[image: mata field]

Here is code:

```
add_filter( 'cmb_meta_boxes', 'cmb_sample_metaboxes' );
function cmb_sample_metaboxes( array $meta_boxes ) {

    $prefix = '_single_';

    $meta_boxes[] = array(
        'id'         => 'coupons_metabox',
        'title'      => 'Coupon details',
        'pages'      => array( 'coupons', ), // Post type
        'context'    => 'normal',
        'priority'   => 'high',
        'show_names' => true, // Show field names on the left
        'fields' => array(
            array( // Text Input
                'name' => 'The date the coupon expires', // <label>
                'desc'  => 'The expiration date of the coupon. Leave if empty if the coupon doesn\'t have an expiration date.', // description
                'id'    => $prefix . 'date', // field id and name
                'type'  => 'text_date_timestamp', // type of field,
                ),
        )
    );

    // Add other metaboxes as needed

    return $meta_boxes;
   }

add_action( 'init', 'cmb_initialize_cmb_meta_boxes', 9999 );
/**
 * Initialize the metabox class.
 */
function cmb_initialize_cmb_meta_boxes() {

    if ( ! class_exists( 'cmb_Meta_Box' ) )
        require_once 'init.php';

}
```

Comment: The right place to ask this question is the cmb forums

Comment: Please be very clear what you want. This update renders my answer useless. Please be sure you add all info before you post a question so that no one wastes their time answering irrelevant info

Comment: Sorry for that . Actually i want to change date format like month-day-year to day-month-year.

Comment: That is info that should be **in** your question, and not in a comment where nobody actually sees it

Answer (score 1):

### EDIT

You should be using [`date_create_from_format`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-create-from-format.php) or its alias [`DateTime::createFromFormat()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.createfromformat.php) to convert on format to another. You can try the following

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y', '03-09-2015');
echo $date->format('d-m-Y');
```

This will convert `03-09-2015` to `09-03-2015`

### ORIGINAL ANSWER

This is more a PHP question than Wordpress question. You can simply use [`str_replace`](http://php.net/str_replace) to change the `/` in your date to `-`. You are not changing the format, so no need for `date_format` or any other date related functions

You can try something like

```
$date = '03/09/2015';
$modified_date = str_replace( '/', '-', $date );
echo $modified_date;
```

This will output `03-09-2015`

Comment: See my update. Please read [ask] and visit [help] and take a [tour] to learn how the SE sites work, and how to ask a good question and also see what is on topic and what is not.

Comment: Sorry. How to add this function in wordpress custom meta field ?